# Error when install Wordcloud in python

Tags: python, installation, word-cloud

I tried to install wordcloud by `pip install wordcloud` but have error :

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

full error: [source code](https://pastebin.com/bmt0eUU1)

Help me fix it.

Comment: whats the python version you are using?

Comment: I used python 3.6.2

Comment: The issue is most probably with the incorrect dependencies compatibility, that is required for the wordcloud. Do you have  numpy>=1.5.1, pillow and matplotlib installed for your respective python version? Also I am assuming you have python-dev properly setup in your respective environment.